# no password field in oc_users table opencart

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am unable to login in to admin/ client of my opencart website that is running from a long time. I checked out the .htaccess page and config.php pages too but every thing is fine.

In the database in **oc_users table the password and salt columns are missing** i am trying to figure out what to be done. I gone through the hosting provider and they are also helpless with out those fields.  Any help

**Thankyou**

Comment: Yowch. You're going to need to restore from a backup. As for cause, I'd wager either someone doing something stupid, or a SQL injection hole.